# dhclient asking for new routing every 1500 seconds, removing my static routing, cron not working

Tags: ubuntu, routing, cron, dhclient

I have a problem with cron job on my ubuntu server 12.04. I have two internet providers - one for fast speed, second - for local resources. So, I'm using command route to up the static routing for second provider. But the point is that the dhclient asking every ~1500 seconds new routing from provider and set it up.

```
Sep 14 18:00:57 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.166.132.69 on eth2 to 80.73.64.167 port 67
Sep 14 18:00:57 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPNAK from 80.73.64.167
Sep 14 18:00:57 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Sep 14 18:00:58 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.166.132.69 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Sep 14 18:00:58 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 10.166.132.69 from 80.73.64.167
Sep 14 18:00:58 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPACK of 10.166.132.69 from 80.73.64.167
Sep 14 18:00:58 ubuntu dhclient: bound to 10.166.132.69 -- renewal in 1443 seconds.
```

So I think cron can help me to solve this problem. I know this is not the best way. But this is all that I could think of.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

*/5 * * * * root /etc/network/if-up.d/route-eth2 > /tmp/otchetcron

*/5 * * * * root /home/route.sh > /tmp/otchet
```

All files are executable.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1,2K авг.  29 21:50 /etc/network/if-up.d/route-eth2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1,2K сент.  5 23:15 route.sh
```

in output files otchet and otchetcron is nothing. They just empty. In syslog I saw this:

```
Sep 19 18:25:01 ubuntu CRON[9105]: (root) CMD (root /etc/network/if-up.d/route-eth2 > /tmp/otchetcron)
Sep 19 18:25:01 ubuntu CRON[9106]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.d/route.sh > /tmp/otchet)
Sep 19 18:25:01 ubuntu CRON[9104]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep 19 18:25:01 ubuntu CRON[9103]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

So If you have the other ways to solve it. Please give me an advice.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has a feature that may be helpful here.  Linux allows the creation of multiple route tables, but the DHCP client by default will only touch the main table.  So what you could do is setup all your routes for the other ISP on a different table, and add an `ip rule` to have all the packets use the alternate table.

See: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html